# How do I suppress the warning "unable to find the application log" after running "symfony serve"?

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface, symfony4

With Symfony 4.3 and Symfony CLI v4.7.1, when I run:

```
symfony serve
```

I see the following warning in the output:

> WARNING unable to find the application log

How do I solve the issue that raises this warning? Do I have to install the logger bundle?

Comment: is that a new project? if so, `mkdir -p var/log; touch dev.log` (as the correct user!) might do the trick (creates the log dir and adds a file for the dev environment)

Comment: tbh, it's hard to tell what the `symfony` tool does, because there is no source code publicly available, hence, I'm only guessing here.

Answer (score 6):

I have bumped into the same issue today. For some reason, I had to create an empty log file (`dev.log`) inside the `var/log` directory. After that, the warning disappeared and the log messages appeared in the file.

Answer (score 5):

You have to install the "logger" package:

```
composer require logger
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The `composer update` command in the terminal automatically built all missing files and in particular `var/log/dev.log`.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you've altered the default log file path. In my case, I use `rotating_file` to make sure dev.log doesn't grow too large. `rotating_file` writes to dev-yyyy-mm-dd.log instead of dev.log. Creating an empty dev.log removes the message.